# how to tell xcode to refer a specific xcconfig file for a configuration from command line

Tags: xcode, xcconfig

Is their a way to set xcconfig file for a project from command line much like how cocoa pods does on running pod install ?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? What is the actual build issue you are trying to solve?

Comment: Ok.. so I have multiple xcconfig files with different build settings. What I want is to refer a particular xcconfig file at build time through scheme pre action.. i.e. their will be a scheme for each xcconfig to load that configuration at build time.

Answer (score 0):

So to answer your question directly, `xcodebuild` has the flag `-xcconfig filename`. Read the documentation for the command with `man xcodebuild`.

Comment: Thats one way I know, I needed the way pods does it to set the xcconfig file directly in project configuration.